# How to install mongodb in Ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I am installing Mongodb in Ubuntu and get following error message :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-214-154-88:/var/lib/mongodb$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
connecting to: test
2015-10-26T11:45:14.257+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-10-26T11:45:14.267+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

I tried to solve this problem :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
```

but above solution does not work for me.

I also check space on server :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-214-154-88:/var/lib/mongodb$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.3G  3.1G  59% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           377M  356K  377M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       3.9G  8.1M  3.7G   1% /mnt
```

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Check if mongod is running on your system.
If not first start it as a daemon . On my system it is running as "/usr/bin/mongod" 
After that type mongo on terminal and initiate the client

Comment: I have following error messages in mongo logs : 
options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }
journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Insufficient free space for journal files
Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal
exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals
now exiting
shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: @NileshKumar try cmd option `--smallfiles` https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--smallfiles

Comment: @MiKeBu How can i use --smallfiles to connect with mongo ?

Comment: @NileshKumar use `/usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles` on the server-side. Your previous error says `Insufficient free space for journal files`. So you need to switch off journal (`--nojournal`) or use smaller journal files (`--smallfiles`).